# C# Variables is loading tags in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have inserted a web.config key as below:

```
<add key="WebInstance" value="/testApp"/>
```

When I call my Site.Master

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= WebInstance%>/themes/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

In my Site.Master.cs

```
private string _webInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebInstance"]

public string WebInstance { get { return _webInstance ; }}
```

The first referencing in Site.Master works perfectly. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/testApp/themes/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

But in the other pages, it references the full tag.

For instance, when I do `inspect element` on the browser function, what I see on my `<head></head>` tags are these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= WebInstance %>/themes/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css"  />
```

I also had the functions of getting the key on my ascx.cs

Why is it just calling the tag instead of getting the real value?

**UPDATE**

SITE.MASTER and the 'other' pages are 2 different things, the `WebInstance` key is from the `web.config` file.

In Site.Master.cs I have its own function to call to the Key and also the other pages have their own respective functions to call the Key.

[image: Please take a look at the attached image for better understanding.]

**UPDATE AGAIN**

I have found the answer to all this, I had `runat="server"` on my `<Head></Head>` tags on the other pages, removing it solved the problem. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: `Site.Master` is not a page, it is a master page, you cannot open it on its own. Can you explain what exactly do you mean by "The first referencing in Site.Master works perfectly."?

Comment: What I mean is, those page that inherited from Site.Master will be able to reference to the style pages properly based on the key, but for some other pages when I did the same, instead, it shows `<%= WebInstance %>` as a physical path and not converting it to the key I want.

Comment: What is different between these other pages and the pages that work fine?

Comment: Is it on static html pages where its not working, by any chance?

Comment: Instead of just showing us code that does work, how about showing us where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes @Jamiec I would say, when I build and successfully run the web application, pages that inherited from Site.Master is able to reference the style pages as `src="/testApp/......css"`. But other pages that don't inherit from it, will reference the style pages like `src="<%= WebInstance %>/.....css"`

Comment: Did you not simply intend a link to ~/themes/...

Comment: @NewbieCoder, that is very confusing. How do you expect pages that do not use the master page still be able to pick up something defined in this master page?

Comment: @Andrei, I mentioned "OTHER PAGES THAT DON'T INHERIT FROM MASTER PAGE". But it certainly has its own function that calls the web.config key from the aspx.cs

Comment: Think of the code-behind for your master page as a separate class. Other classes can't access its properties unless they are static. If you made that property static and referenced `Site.WebInstance` it would work. But don't do that. `Site.Master` should contain only code-behind for that page. It shouldn't be a place where code used for other pages is stored. If you need a separate class to house common functions then you should create that.

Comment: You all are complicating yourselves, I had `runat="server"` in my head tags, so it doesn't call the C# Variable from the `.cs` page.

Answer (score 1):

Your other pages can't directly reference code-behind in their master page.
You could add the same property to your individual pages, but then you get duplication.
Although I'm not a big fan of static classes, in this case it might be good compromise:

```
public static class SiteSettings
{
    public string WebInstance
    { 
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebInstance"];}}
    }
}
```

Then in your .aspx, reference `SiteSettings.WebInstance`.

Some developers will make a base page that other pages inherit from and put common properties there. That can work but I'd use it as a last resort. Sooner or later you're going to want some behaviors of the base page but not others, or you'll have to make some broad changes to the site and it becomes a big pain.